# Is there a way to restrict the number of nodes for a MapReduce program?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

In my Spark program, I can kind of restrict the number of nodes my program would be running on by ajdusting the `--num-executors` parameter. Now I want to compare the scalability of my program with a similar MapReduce program. But for that I would also need to restrict the number of nodes for it.

I am running both programs on a cluster where I don't have any admin rights. So, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In MapReduce you can restrict the number of reducers 
( in your case make reducers = number of node needed),

Number of mappers spawned will be based on the InputFormat.
What you can do is carefully calculate the InputSize based on the InputFormat which should be = number of nodes expected.

To give you an example.

```
InputFormat = TextInputFormat. 
Input Text File size = 2 GB  
TextInputFormat split size( defaults to hdfs block size) = 128 MB
```

in this case you will see 16 Mappers running . If you have 16 nodes all of them will run in parallel across all the nodes.

(Do understand this is like best case, you might still see mappers running on same node)

Please follow http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/ for detailed understanding

Comment: I gave the example for TextInputFormat.

lets take TableInputFormat . 
create a table with  X predefined regions .   where X = number of Nodes expected.  

Write some data for each split . and run MR on the same.

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/hbase/hbase-readwrite-from-map-reduce/

Comment: oh no, number of regions in table is not a subject of cluster restrictions

Comment: the next day manager says you should use 16 nodes instead of 24 and I not gonna rebuild my table